# How to update google sheet data?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, next.js, google-sheets-api

am getting an error while updating google sheet data using next js, i am getting an error like **ReferenceError: row is not defined** don't know where i am wrong, please try to fix my error, If you have any question please free feel to ask, don't be hesitate.

[image]

> sheet.js

This is the file where i wrote my updated code.

```
export async function updateDataFromSheets() {
  try {

    const target = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
    const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
      process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      null,
      (process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_PRIVATE_KEY || '').replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      target
    );

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: jwt });

    let values = [
      [
        'pravinkale889@gmail.com',
        'pravin kale',
        'BE Comp',
        'Success'
      ],
      // Additional rows ...
    ];
    const resource = {
      values,
    };
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId: process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: 'sheet',
      valueInputOption: row[6],
      resource
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('%d cells updated.', result.updatedCells);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return [];
}
```

> index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

import { getDataFromSheets } from '../libs/sheets';

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Nextsheet </title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Nextsheet </h1>
        <p>Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database</p>
        <ul>
          {data && data.length ? (
            data.map((item) => (
              <li key={item}>
               {item.Email} - {item.Subject} - {item.Body} - {item.Status}
              </li>
            ))
          ) : (
            <li>Error: do not forget to setup your env variables </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
export async function getStaticProps() {

  const sheet = await getDataFromSheets();

  return {
    props: {
      data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sheet.slice(0, sheet.length))), // remove sheet header
    },
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  };
}
```

> dynamicid.js

```
import { getDataFromSheets } from '../../../libs/sheets';
import sendmail from '../../../libs/ses/sendmail';
import { updateDataFromSheets } from '../../../libs/sheets';

    export default function handler(req, res) {
      var data;
      getDataFromSheets()
        .then(sheet => {
          data = sheet.length
          for (var i = 1; i < data; i++) {
            if (sheet[i].Status != 'Success') {
              sendmail(sheet[i].Email, sheet[i].Subject, sheet[i].Body)
            }
          }
          res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'email has been sent' })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          res.json({ status: 'fail', error: err })
        })
    
      updateDataFromSheets();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that from your error message, your error message is due to `valueInputOption: row[6],`. In your script, `row` is not declared. I think that this is the reason for your issue. For example, the value of `valueInputOption` can be used `RAW` or `USER_ENTERED`. In your situation, I would like to propose using `USER_ENTERED`. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
valueInputOption: row[6],
```

#### To:

```
valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
```

#### Note:

- When I tested your script using my sample Spreadsheet shared with the email of service account, I confirmed that your script works by the above modification. But when your Spreadsheet cannot be used with the service account, an error might occur. So please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)